# DataTable not refreshing in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, datatable, angular6

```html
<div class="row-fluid padTop5">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="showFiles">
      <div class="col-12 colBorder">
        <table datatable class="table table-striped centerAlign">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="centerAlign">Select All<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="fileSelectAll" name="fileSelectAll" class="d-block" (change)="selectAll($event,fileSelectAll)"></th>
              <th>TestCase Name</th>
              <!-- <th>Provision Name</th> -->
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let file of fileList;let i =index">
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="file.selected" [checked]="isSelected" (change)='checkClicked($event,file)' name="cb">
              </td>
              <td>{{file.name}}</td>
              <!-- <td>PE</td> -->
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using angular datatables ..the table is forming when the user selects the file from local.works fine for the first time..but when the user again selects the file previous records are not gone..how to. Refresh the table

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. you should share your code here

Comment: @Bear Nithi- I have mailed you the HTML file as from phone I am not able to upload the code in stack overflow

Comment: @Bear Nithi--updated the code . Please check once.

Comment: @trincot please have a look